# How to translate city/region dropdown on magento 2

Tags: checkout, magento-2.1, js-translation

The city/region drop-down list on checkout page is not translatable with .csv files I tried everything but it didn't work.

Does anyone have an idea?

Magento 2.1.2, Community edition.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those translations are located into the database.

You can create a specific module to setup your data. 
You need to update the *directory_country_region_name* table using *region_id* field from the *directory_country_region* table.

Comment: Yeah I have already done it just like this. I've just changed the region id for the specific language and it changed then. But thanks anyways.