# Get region name in default language

Tags: language, multi-language

I am new to this Magento community and stuck at a very basic thing. I am getting the region(state) name from a customer address with this code

```
$billingAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($billingAddressId);
$RegionName = $billingAddress->getRegion();
```

Now some regions are being returned in locale language. One example is - 
**Oberösterreich**. I want this to be translated in default en_GB language.

I was facing a similar issue with country name as well, though figured out a solution for that as -

```
$locale = new Zend_Locale('en_GB');
$countries = $locale->getTranslationList('Territory', $locale->getLanguage(), 2);
$countryName = $countries[$billingAddress->getCountryId()];
```

This was converting the returned name from **Deutschland** to **Germany**

I am seeking the same solution for the region name as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no translated names of regions in  Magento. Did You check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158250/how-to-translate-city-region-dropdown-on-magento-2

Comment: @BartZalas I've checked by getting region name after changing the site's default language to English. The region **Oberösterreich** came with the same name again. I think there is no other translation exist for this name and its a static string there. Am I right?

Comment: They are but they located in database. The fastest way is to change manually in database. Also read comment from my link

Answer (score 3):

For getting the region in your locale you just need to add it to **directory_country_region_name** table and based on the stores locale it will be fetched correctly.
So, if you have a region like below:

`region_id`,`country_id`,`code`,`default_name`

1001, IN, DE, Delhi

then the directory_country_region_name table data will look like below for en_US locale:

`locale`,`region_id`,`name`

'en_US','1001','New Delhi'

**How to get the localized region id based on the current region:**

```
$billingAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($billingAddressId);
$regionId = $billingAddress->getRegionId();

$regionModel = Mage::getModel('directory/region')->load($regionId);
$regionName = $regionModel->getName();
```

Based on the current store locate it will fetch the data from table `directory_country_region_name`
If not found in the table `directory_country_region_name` then default will be loaded.

Comment: I am unable to get your answer. Do you mean I need to convert and save all regions name on my own in a table? As I have `$billingAddressId`, can you share some code snippet that I need to follow to get region name in my desired language.

Comment: @Anant, Let me edit my answer to address your query

Comment: The code you've provided is still returning the region in the same locale and not in the converted locale :(